# Value of object = calculation in models.py

Tags: python, django

I need to use objects data to create the value of another value. See the code. The last object is the one I need to change depending of the other objects.

```
user_current_conversion_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)

user_optimal_conversion_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)

user_monthly_visitors = models.IntegerField(default=0)

user_average_order_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

user_increase_conversion_rate = int(user_monthly_visitors*
    (user_optimal_conversion_rate/100)*
    user_average_order_value)-
    (user_monthly_visitors*
    (user_current_conversion_rate/100)*
    user_average_order_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

just make it a property of the Model

```
user_current_conversion_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)

user_optimal_conversion_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)

user_monthly_visitors = models.IntegerField(default=0)

user_average_order_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

@property
def user_increase_conversion_rate(self):
    return int(self.user_monthly_visitors*
    (self.user_optimal_conversion_rate/100)*
    self.user_average_order_value)-
    (self.user_monthly_visitors*
    (self.user_current_conversion_rate/100)*
    self.user_average_order_value))
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I just need to get help how to use it in the html template.

I tried {{ user_increase_conversion_rate }} but nothing is showing.

Comment: do you have a ModelForm somewhere? That's where I think you can re-define the name of the fields.

Comment: Nope I can't find that. Can I created an object that uses the value of the property def?

Comment: You don't need to *create* an object, you already have one: your model instance. You just need to send that to the template.

Comment: Thanks! How do I do that? I have tried {{ user_increase_conversion_rate }} but not working.

Comment: you must pass the object as context to the renderer. can you show the  ode that returns the rendered template.